# dataform compile fails - Assigning to rvalue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I'm using Dataform CLI in my local machine.
Version : 1.22.2

I followed this guide to run with includes. https://docs.dataform.co/guides/javascript/includes
my sqlx file and constants are same as the documentation.

constants.js

const PROJECT_ID = "my_project_name";
module.exports = { PROJECT_ID };

sqlx

SELECT * FROM ${constants.PROJECT_ID}.schema.table

````
PS C:\Srikanth\vscode\framework> dataform compile
Compiling...

Dataform encountered an error: Assigning to rvalue
C:\user\vscode\repository_1\index.js:25
      try { global.includes/constants = require("./includes/constants.js"); } catch (e) {
            ^

SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue
    at makeNiceSyntaxError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.9.1\node_modules\@dataform\cli\node_modules\vm2\lib\transformer.js:41:16)
    at transformer (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.9.1\node_modules\@dataform\cli\node_modules\vm2\lib\transformer.js:84:8)
    at NodeVM.run (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.9.1\node_modules\@dataform\cli\node_modules\vm2\lib\nodevm.js:414:17)
    at compile (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.9.1\node_modules\@dataform\cli\worker_bundle.js:19829:23)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.9.1\node_modules\@dataform\cli\worker_bundle.js:19834:36)
    at process.emit (node:events:406:35)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:917:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is happening only in Windows machines.

There is already an issue tracked on google site.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279506026

As workaround I modified the related function in the node_module "...\node_modules@dataform\core\bundle.js":

```
const pathSeperator = (() => {
    if (typeof process !== "undefined") {
        return process.platform === "win32" ? "/" : "/";
    }
    return "/";
})();
```

Refer : https://github.com/dataform-co/dataform/issues/1486

Also update to more recent version of dataform cli (Used - 2.3.2)